# Displaying a text file in Java

Tags: java, readfile

I am a beginner in Java programming.

I have a text file, for example `C:/Temp/dat.txt`.

This is the code I have set in the **Main Class**:

```
public static boolean readFile(String filename) {
    File file = new File(filename);

    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
            String[] words = scanner.nextLine().split(",");

            int id = Integer.parseInt(words[0]);
            String firstName = words[1];
            String lastName = words[2];
            int mathMark1 = Integer.parseInt(words[3]);
            int mathMark2 = Integer.parseInt(words[4]);
            int mathMark3 = Integer.parseInt(words[5]);
            int englishMark1 = Integer.parseInt(words[6]);
            int englishMark2 = Integer.parseInt(words[7]);
            int englishMark3 = Integer.parseInt(words[8]);

            addStudent(id,firstName,lastName,mathMark1,mathMark2,mathMark3,englishMark1,englishMark2,englishMark3); 
        }
        scanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Failed to read file");
    }
    return true;
}
```

I now need to display this data from the text file under the following method:

```
private static void displayReportByMarks() {

}
```

How do I get the report to display from the *text file* within this method, and what is the appropriate code to put(if any) in the Main method of this class.

I hope this makes sense, as I said I am a complete novice at Java and can't get my head around this.

Many thanks

Amanda

Comment: What does `addStudent` do? Are there multiple students? What is the report supposed to look like?

Comment: what are you expecting from displayReportByMarks() ? what is the problem

Comment: If understand you correctly then you need to call the method `readFile(filename)` from inside `displayReportByMarks`. I guess the `addStudent` part takes care of the the printing part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you have a `Stundent` implemented as a staandard POJO, first implement the `addStudent` method:

```
private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

private static void addStudent(int id, String firstName, String lastName, 
                               int mathMark1, int mathMark2, int mathMark3, 
                               int englishMark1, int englishMark2,
                               int englishMark3) {
    students.add(new Student(id, firstName, lastName, mathMark1, mathMark2,
                     mathMark3, englishMark1, englishMark2,englishMark3));
}
```

Then, you can implement the printing method:

```
private static void displayReportByMarks() {
     List<Student> studentsByMarks = students.stream().sorted(
             (s1, s2) -> //just do the comparison for sorting here
             )).collect(Collectors.toList());
     for (Student : students) {
          // assuming you have a Student.toString() method implemeted.
          System.out.println(student);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first trick is to do away with all those `static`-s and have one object of the Main class worked on. In the `main` method create a Main object.

Then there is much that is not told, how to get the students, so one might sort/reorder them and loop through them. But that would be your homework anyway.
Sketchy it would be the following.

```
public class Main {
    private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().process();
    }

    private void process() {
        ...
        displayReportByMarks();
    }

    private void displayReportByMarks() {
         Collections.sort(students, ...); // On marks.
         students.sort(...); // Or this.
         for (Student : students) {
             ...
         }
    }
```

Comment: In case you are wondering where to read the file, once you removed the `static` from your `readFile()` method you can call it in your `process()` method (of course before you call `displayReportByMarks()`  :).